# Is it possible to automatically translate Java bytecode to IJVM?

Tags: java, bytecode, jvm-bytecode, ijvm

Is it possible to automatically translate Java bytecode to IJVM? Is there any possibility you know?

Answer (score 0):

IJVM contains a subset of the JVM instruction set, so you could claim it is possible, theoretically, to automatically convert a *set* of programs that would be compiled only to that particular instruction subset.

I don't know of anything that would actually do it, though. The point of IJVM is to teach assembly, so I suppose that would be counterproductive.